# How to process each frames exactly only once using MediaStreamTrackProcessor

Tags: javascript, html5-video, webcodecs, mediastreamtrack

I can't seem to be able to process each frames of a video only once using MediaStreamTrackProcessor.

I'm building a web app where I need to process each frames individually, only once, at a pre-defined pace.

Initially, I was using `requestAnimationFrame`, calculating the frame displayed using a known constant (FPS) and the currentTime attribute of the video element, and making sure I only process the frame if not already done. This is not ideal as the browser can sometimes skip video frames and we don't have control over that.

Similarly, I started using `requestVideoFrameCallback`, which is much better because this API is only called when a new frame was displayed on the screen, but it still has the same limitation where the browser can skip some frames.

I then went and tested the Web Codecs API (MediaStreamTrackProcessor) which is meant to do exactly that, processing frame by frame, but it turns out that I can't figure out how to process each frames ONLY ONCE, the reader stream is emitting at a much higher rate than the video playback, and it seems to emit the same frame multiple times if the video is playing back slowly.

See example here:
https://codepen.io/Kevin-Dorion/pen/ZEZpybJ

So, question is, how do I make sure I only process each frame once in the reader?

Comment: _"I need to process each frames individually, only once, at a pre-defined pace"_ Does it have to be done using **MediaStreamTrackProcessor**? If you simply want to step through an MP4 video frame by frame, you can do it with seeking a `<video>` tag if you know the input's FPS.

Comment: There is no such thing as accurate seeking even if you know the FPS. This being said, it would be awfully slow.

"Note: Unfortunately, the video element does not guarantee frame-accurate seeking. This has been an ongoing subject of discussion. The WebCodecs API allows for frame accurate applications."

Source: https://web.dev/articles/requestvideoframecallback-rvfc

Comment: **(1)** _"There is no such thing as accurate seeking even if you know the FPS"_ That's not my experience. Do you have a link to an MP4 that doesn't seek accurately? I'll test it for you. I do MP4 frame stepping all the time in Chrome for my video effects output. I've never seen it skip a frame when testing with a time-coded video. **(2)** Yes webCodecs can do it too but your code is not using `WebCodecs`, it is using `MediaStream`, where the `captureStream` part is like requesting a live recording (and as you found out, it can emit faster than the video FPS)...

Comment: **(3)** To use webCodecs you must know how to work with bytes and then also prepare your input. Use MP4 encoded with Baseline profile (since Main and High, by their design, will be awkward to frame step sequentially with their B-frames involved). You must also know how to extract individual H264 frame's bytes from within the MP4 bytes (you can try using something like Mux.js for that part or else it's time to read some PDFs for coding your own functions)

Comment: **(4)** You can avoid webCodecs by using MediaStream's **appendBuffer** instead of **captureStream** to achieve frame by frame. You still need the specific bytes of a frame., so it too means knowing H264 bytes. **(5) Finally...** Seeking the `<video>` just works and avoids the need to know some file bytes structure. Why do you think it would be slower? Also I can test any file you provide to show you a working result. PS: Sorry it's long.